# Bijection from $\mathbb Z$ to $\{\pm2+\frac1{n+1}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{ 2+\frac{1}{n+1} ,\quad -2+\frac{1}{n+1} \mid\quad n=0,1,\ldots \}$.

Find a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $A$.

I try to set $f : \mathbb{Z} \to A $ where $f(k)=2+\frac{1}{k+1}$ if $k\geq 0$ and $f(k)=-2+\frac{1}{k+1} $ if $k <0 $. But this does not work.

Can you give some ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by isomorphism?

Comment: The word "isomorphism" is usually reserved for situations where the sets involved are closed under some operation. Is there an operation under which $A$ is closed? Or are you just asking for a one-one onto map between the two sets?

Comment: do you mean $f(k)=2+\frac{1}{k+1}$?

Comment: Do you mean bijection?

Comment: Yes i mean a one-to-one and bijection map from Z to A.

Comment: @Pjennings:you are right. I edit it.

Comment: What is $A$? Is $A$ the set that contains all rationals of the form $2+\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $-2+\frac{1}{n+1}$, with $n=0,1,\ldots,$? I ask because your notation is at best confusing.

Comment: @ Arturo: Yes that's what I mean. Sorry for the bad notation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Don't forget isomorphisms in the category of sets ;)

Comment: @Michalis, I had that in mind when I wrote "usually".

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Can you find a bijection between $\{m\in\mathbb{Z}\mid m\geq 0\}$ and $\{2 + \frac{1}{n+1}\mid n=0,1,2,\ldots\}$?
2. Can you find a bijection between $\{m\in\mathbb{Z}\mid m\geq 0\}$ and $\{-2+\frac{1}{n+1}\mid 0,1,2,\ldots\}$?
3. Can you find a bijection between $\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\mid k\lt 0\}$ and $\{m\in\mathbb{Z}\mid m\geq 0\}$?

Comment: :I can find the above bijections but I still can't solve the problem.

Comment: @passenger: Put them together! Use the bijections in 3 and in 2 to get a bijection from the *negative* integers to $\{-2+\frac{1}{n+1}\mid n=0,1,2,\ldots\}$; use the bijection on 1 to get a bijection from the nonnegative integers to $\{2+\frac{1}{n+1}\mid n=0,1,2,\ldots\}$. Now define your bijection as being the first function on the negatives, and the second function on the nonnegatives. What is the problem?

Comment: :No problem! Silly question! I do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your idea almost works. Make no change when $k \ge 0$. When $k<0$, send $k$ to $-2+\frac{1}{|k|}$.

**Comment:** Before we get to formulas, let's think about what the set $A$ looks like. It consists of

$2+\frac{1}{1}$, $2+\frac{1}{2}$, $2+\frac{1}{3}$, and so on, together with

$-2+\frac{1}{1}$, $-2+\frac{1}{2}$, $-2+\frac{1}{3}$, and so on.

It seems reasonable to send $0$ to $2+\frac{1}{1}$, to send $1$ to $2+\frac{1}{2}$, to send $2$ to $2+\frac{1}{3}$, and so on.  The definition of $f(k)$ for $k \ge 0$ is then clear.

Then it seems natural to send $-1$ to $-2+\frac{1}{1}$, to send $-2$ to $-2+\frac{1}{2}$, to send $-3$ to $-2+\frac{1}{3}$, and so on.  The definition of $f(k)$ for $k < 0$ is then clear. (Instead of writing $2-\frac{1}{|k|}$ we could write $f(k)=-2-\frac{1}{k}$.  But I feel more comfortable with positive numbers.)

The fact that $f$ is bijective is intuitively absolutely obvious, and (almost) does not require proof. However, if proof is asked for, it is easy to write down.

Comment: @@Andre Nicolas:I think you mean $ -2+\frac{1}{|k|+1} $ when $k<0$. I try this too, but I could not prove that is one-to-one, when $k_1 \geq 0$ and $ k_2<0$ why $ f(k_1)=f(k_2)$?

Comment: @passenger: you mean $f(k_1)\neq f(k_2)$: because $f(k_2) = -2+\frac{1}{|k_2|+1}\lt 0$, but $f(k_1) = 2+\frac{1}{k_1+1} \gt 0$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin:Yes my mistake sorry! It is obvious!

Comment: @passenger: It is $1/|k|$, because we are looking at negative $k$. The first number we want to "hit" is $-2+\frac{1}{1}$, and it is nice to let this be $f(-1)$. We want also $f(-2)=-2+\frac{1}{2}$, and so on. The situation is not quite symmetric, because of $0$. If you want to show that if $k_1\ge 0$ and $k_2<0$, then $f(k_1)\ne f(k_2)$ [note typo in your comment above], this is obvious. It is clear that $f(k_1)$ is positive, indeed $f(k_1)>2$.  And it is clear that $f(k_2)$ is negative, for $f(k_2)=-2+1/|k_2| \le -1$. So they can't be equal.

Comment: @AndreNicolas: It is clear!Thank you for your answer!